# Is Python-OpenID going through Janrain?

Tags: python, openid, janrain

I'm looking to implement OpenID in my python based project, and a good implementation is [Python-OpenID](https://github.com/openid/python-openid), maintained by [Janrain](http://www.janrain.com/openid-enabled).

But [Janrain is free only when there is less than 2.500 unique sign-in/registration](http://www.janrain.com/products/engage/get-janrain-engage).

I was wondering if this limitation is linked to Python-OpenID.
What happens if you reach this 2.500 quota ? Nothing (because Python-OpenID doesn't really use Janrain) or it stops working ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, it's an OpenID library, so it doesn't have anything to do with Janrain Engage. And it doesn't stop working because you have too many users.